Null object reference when trying to use my bluetooth service in android
I have created a bluetooth service that should be handling the connection in the background after it has connected with the other device. I currently have 2 files where one is the service and the other one is an activity that interacts with the service to establish a connection. My service code looks like this:
public class BTservice extends Service {



    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");


    Context mContext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;

    ListView lvNewDevices;

    public BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;


    public BTservice(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }


    public BTservice(){
        super();

    }
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread(){
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try{
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try{
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if(socket != null){
                connected(socket,mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            }

            //will talk about this in the 3rd video
            connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**

     AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth"
                ,"Please Wait...",true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try{
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("incomingMessage", incomingMessage);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }

    public final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch(state){
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    public final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                        break;
                    //Device not in discoverable mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };




    /**
     * Broadcast Receiver for listing devices that are not yet paired
     * -Executed by btnDiscover() method.
     */
    public BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra (BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mBTDevices.add(device);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);
                lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Broadcast Receiver that detects bond state changes (Pairing status changes)
     */
    public final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)){
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //3 cases:
                //case1: bonded already
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
                    //inside BroadcastReceiver4
                    mBTDevice = mDevice;
                }
                //case2: creating a bone
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                }
                //case3: breaking a bond
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        public void startConnection(){
            startBTConnection(mBTDevice,MY_UUID_INSECURE);
        }

        /**
         * starting chat service method
         */
        public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid){
            Log.d(TAG, "startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection.");

            startClient(device,uuid);
        }



        public void enableDisableBT(){
            if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
            }
            if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
                Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivity(enableBTIntent);

                IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
            }
            if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

                IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
            }

        }
        public void enableDisc(){
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}

And my activity interacting with the service looks like this:
public class BTconnect2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "BTconnect";
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Button btnEnableDisable_Discoverable;


    BTservice.LocalBinder mBTserviceLocalBinder;
    BTservice mBTservice;

    Button btnStartConnection;
    Button btnSend;
    Button backbtn;
    Button test2;

    EditText etSend;
    String text = "this is a test";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;

    ListView lvNewDevices;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        startService(new Intent(this, BTservice.class));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.btconnect);
        Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);
        btnEnableDisable_Discoverable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscoverable_on_off);
        lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
        mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

        btnStartConnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartConnection);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        etSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        backbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbtn);
        test2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton2);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(BTconnect2.this);


        btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
                mBTserviceLocalBinder.enableDisableBT();
            }
        });

        btnStartConnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mBTserviceLocalBinder.startConnection();
            }
        });

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                mBTservice.write(bytes);
            }
        });

        backbtn.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(BTconnect2.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }));

        test2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                mBTservice.write(bytes);
            }
        });
    }

    public void btnEnableDisable_Discoverable(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Making device discoverable for 300 seconds.");
        mBTserviceLocalBinder.enableDisc();

    }

    public void btnDiscover(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBTservice.mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBTservice.mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is required for all devices running API23+
     * Android must programmatically check the permissions for bluetooth. Putting the proper permissions
     * in the manifest is not enough.
     *
     * NOTE: This will only execute on versions > LOLLIPOP because it is not needed otherwise.
     */
    private void checkBTPermissions(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }








    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

        //create the bond.
        //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
            mBTservice= new BTservice(BTconnect2.this);
        }
    }




}

However, whenever i try to use any of the buttons i get an error about a null object reference for example trying to enable bluetooth:
2024-11-13 19:20:34.590 20202-20202/com.example.bluetooth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bluetooth, PID: 20202
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.bluetooth.BTservice$LocalBinder.enableDisableBT()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bluetooth.BTconnect2$1.onClick(BTconnect2.java:86)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21164)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


this is essentially the same error with all the buttons. Am i missing an object that needs to be parsed or why do i get this error?
I have tried implementing the functionality of the buttons in both the service and the interacting part of the app but neither works and returns the error about a null object reference.

Isn't this always null: BTservice.LocalBinder mBTserviceLocalBinder;? No value is assigned anywhere?

Removed android-studio tag as this question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product

You are getting null pointer exception due to mBTserviceLocalBinder is null so you  need to initialise mBTserviceLocalBinder like this :
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: connected to service.");
        mBTserviceLocalBinder = (BTservice.LocalBinder) service;
        mBTservice = mBTserviceLocalBinder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected: disconnected from service.");
        mBTservice = null;
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.btconnect);

    // ... other code

    // Bind to the service
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BTservice.class);
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

